# Access collection data on wix

Tags: node.js, velo

one of my clients has a wealth of data stored in collections on their WIX website. I looked for a node library to access the data.  But "wix-data" has been shut down. How does one usually access collections on Wix?  Their documentation seems to think I'm building an add-on application or an app within their infrastructure.

Does anyone have any hints?

Thanks for your help.

D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any node library, it comes out-of-the-box with Velo by Wix.
Take a look at the API reference of wix-data: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data.
This article can also prove useful in order to learn how to work with the wix-data api: https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-working-with-the-data-api

Answer (score 0):

As jacobk said, you don´t need to work with external libraries

You can access the content using this code:

```
wixData.query('Database Id')
    .eq('Column id', Name in database field)
    .find()
    .then(res => {
        const item = res.items[0];
```

You can read more about it in https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/wixdataquery